# Problems with Bootstrap datepicker in MVC.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

So I'm trying to use a datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

I'm having the problem to set a default value for this datepicker. It shows me the format "0001-01-01 00:00:00" before I can set a date. What I want to do is to show **todays** date!
I create the DOM as follows, which isn't a problem..

```
<div>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidationValidFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ValidationValidFrom" }})
</div>
```

This creates the input with the id "ValidationValidFrom".
And my jQuery code for the datepicker is as follows:

```
$("#ValidationValidFrom").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

The only thing that works is the attribute **format**, the **defaultDate** doesn't work for some reason, I have tried other attributes shown in other threads, but to no avail..

The generated code looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ValidationValidFrom must be a date." data-val-required="The ValidationValidFrom field is required." id="ValidationValidFrom" name="ValidationValidFrom" type="datetime" value="0001-01-01 00:00:00">
```

Comment: What value are you setting `model.ValidationValidFrom` (and please confirm the data type and datatype anotation) in your model in the controller?

Comment: With `EditorFor`, you don't need to specify ID and it will likely break your binding.

Comment: @freedomn-m tried to remove the ID, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry - meant to mark that comment as off-topic.  It's not relevant to *displaying* the data - it will just make it harder when you post to that model - but if you're posting to a different model, it's fine.

Comment: Further to the query above: what does your EditFor render as (with value) before you call the js .datepicker?

Comment: you mean the DOM it generates? I'll put the code in the question above.

Comment: This bit: `value="0001-01-01 00:00:00"` is coming from your model.  You need to set it in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

The `EditorFor` generates an input and sets the value to the value of the model's property.

In this case, the model's property is `model.ValidationValidFrom`.

Without confirmation, this is most likely a DateTime, ie:

```
public class MyModel { 
    public DateTime ValidationValidFrom { get; set; }
```

if a datetime is not given a value, it will be the default value: 0001-01-01.

You can set the value in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyView() {
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.ValidationValidFrom = DateTime.Today;  // or .Now to include time
    return View(model);
```

---

The reason the js `defaultDate` is not changing it from 0001-01-01 is because the `<input>` already has a value, so can't be set to a 'default'.

You could change this by changing the property to a `DateTime?` and leaving it null in the controller.  This would generate an input with `value=""` and then the js should give it a default value.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this, this looks more logical. You'll hear from me!